# Query ontology in Eclipse jena

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse with JENA server to QUERY my ontology. But I got an error and it is not working. The errors are:

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.readModelWorker(FileManager.java:378)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:297)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:248)
at jena.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can get an urgent response if you pay a consultant to help you. You might get a useful answer here if you provide more details, including the code that's causing the problem and the whole of the actual error message you're getting.

Comment: Same stack trace here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712452/6505

Comment: Rook is right, to get a quick response, you should show all the necessary bits in your question (see [mcve]). You should also tell us about your attempts to fix it